# How to simply combine JS functions in one file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with some simple IF / show/ hide scripts.

I've managed to get the independent parts of to scripts working but for some reason together they conflict and I don't know how to combine the two into one file.

Both are designed to show a new form fields when a previous one is selected

First:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 

$("#tukreward").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#tukreward").val() == "interested")
        $("#tukFollow").show();
  
     else 
  $("#tukFollow").hide();
}
```

Second:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 
    $("#accident").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#accident").val() == "yes")
        $("#accidentFollow").show();
  
     else 
  $("#accidentFollow").hide();

  }
```

Independently of each other they work fine but if I save both as separate files and load the page one works and the other doesn't. I've tried combing into one file but I don't know if I'm missing a piece of formatting.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion, change `$("#accident").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });` to `$("#accident").change(toggleFields)`

Answer (score 0):

They both create and call a function `toggleFields()`. When you load in a second script, the second overwrites the firsts definition. The easiest solution is just to change the second file's `toggleFields` to `toggleFields2`

Comment: NO you didn't suggest `toggleFields2`. How `toggleTuk` and `toggleAccident`?

Comment: Taken your advice there as I will be adding many more as I go along

Comment: You'd be better off to create a single `toggleFields` function that is generalized to handle all inputs. Just creating a new function with identical functionality but different parameters for *every* use case is madness.

Answer (score 0):

Its not best practice to use same function names across different js Files. The External Js can be used to define common functions across pages and can be included in pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two functions with the same name, the second one overrides the first one.

My suggestion is to use a single function and add parameters so you avoid duplication.

```
// First file
function toggleFields(fieldToCheckQuery, fieldToCheckShowValue, fieldToShowHideQuery) {
  if ($(fieldToCheckQuery).val() == fieldToCheckShowValue) {
    $(fieldToShowHideQuery).show();
  } else {
    $(fieldToShowHideQuery).hide();
  }
}

// Second file
function toggleTuk() {
    toggleFields("#tukreward", "interested", "#tukFollow");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  toggleTuk(); 
  $("#tukreward").change(toggleTuk);
}

// Third file
function toggleAccident() {
  toggleFields("#accident", "yes", "#accidentFollow");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  toggleAccident(); 
  $("#accident").change(toggleAccident);
```

});